# Let $R$ be a ring. Find out if $R$ is a field and solve the equation $x^2-3x+1=0$ in $R$ given the following addition and multiplication tables.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring. Find out if $R$ is a field and solve the equation $x^2-3x+1=0$ in $R$ given the following addition and multiplication tables.

> [image]

If $R$ was a field then for every element $x \in R$ we need an $x^{-1}$ such that $xx^{-1}=b$ as $b$ is the identity w.r.t $(\cdot)$.

However there is no element $y$ for which $ay=b$ so $R$ cannot be a field.

To solve $x^2-3x+1=0$ I should check which element from $\{a,b,c,d\}$ makes this true?

For $a$ I have that $$aa-(a+a+a)+1= a-(a+a)+1=a-a+1=1$$ and for $b$ $$bb-(b+b+b)+1=b-(c+b)+1=b-d+1$$

for $c$ $$cc-(c+c+c)+1=a-(a+c)+1=a-c+1$$ lastly for $d$ $$dd-(d+d+d)+1=b-(c+d)+1=b-b+1=1.$$

The first and last equations seems to give me $1$, but how can I get rid of the $1$?

Comment: In a field, not every element has an inverse. Just the non-zero elements.

Comment: And $a$ seems to be zero element since it's the identity with resepect to $+$?

Comment: But for $c$ there is no element that produces $b$ so I suppose that that implies that $R$ is not a field. @CaptainLama

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is correct.

Comment: Also, to solve the equation you should remember that in this case $1=b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is prudent to relabel the variables as $abcd\to0123$ so that $R\cong\mathbb Z_4$, which is indeed not a field. Then it is easy to check that $x^2-3x+1=x^2+x+1$ has no solutions in $\mathbb Z_4$, hence $R$.